# ASP.NET MVC 6 handling errors based on HTTP status code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to display different error messages for each status code e.g:

- 400 Bad Request
- 403 Forbidden
- 500 Internal Server Error
- 404 Not Found
- 401 Unauthorized

How can I achieve this in the new ASP.NET MVC 6 applications? Can I do this using the built in UseErrorHandler method?

```
application.UseErrorHandler("/error");
```

Also, I noticed that even with the above handler, entering a non-existent URL e.g. /this-page-does-not-exist, causes an ugly 404 Not Found error page from IIS. How can this also be handled?

In MVC 5 we have had to use the system.web customerrors section for ASP.NET **and** the system.webServer httpErrors section in the web.config file but it was difficult to work with an unwieldy, with lots of very strange behaviour. Does MVC 6 make this a lot simpler?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the `StatusCodePagesMiddleware` for this. Following is an example:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/StatusCodes/StatusCode{0}");

    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

Controller which handles the status code requests:

```
public class StatusCodesController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult StatusCode404()
    {
        return View(viewName: "NotFound"); // you have a view called NotFound.cshtml
    }

    ... more actions here to handle other status codes
}
```

Some Notes:

- Check other extension methods like `UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects`
  and `UseStatusCodePages` for other capabilities.
- I tried having StatusCode as a query string in my example, but looks like this
  middleware doesn't handle query strings, but you can take a look at
  [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/3fa5dee2d7f377d57e75fbb0d328cd26b6ff093a/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics/StatusCodePagesExtensions.cs#L121) code and fix this issue.

Comment: Note: This is a better solution then the one I provided below.

Comment: This code executes for all requests. Am I right in saying that this would be added to the Action delegate that can be passed to UseErrorHandler?

Comment: @RehanSaeed: yes, this could would be executed for all requests as it needs to intercept the responses to verify the status code. I am not clear about your second question. This is a different middleware than the `UserErrorHandler`. can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I achieve this in the new ASP.NET MVC 6 applications? Can I do this using the built in UseErrorHandler method?

**Quick answer:** Not in an elegant fashion.

**Explanation/Alternative:** To start lets first look at what the `UseErrorHandler` method is actually doing: https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/6dbbe831c493e6e7259de81f83a04d1654170137/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics/ErrorHandlerExtensions.cs#L25 which adds the following middleware: https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/6dbbe831c493e6e7259de81f83a04d1654170137/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.cs **Note** lines 29-78 (the invoke method)

The invoke method is executed whenever a request comes in (controlled by the location of your `application.UseErrorHandler("...")` in your `Startup.cs`). So the `UseErrorHandler` is a glorified way of adding a custom middleware: middleware = component that can act on an http request.

Now with that background, if we wanted to add our own error middleware that differentiated requests. We could do this by adding a similar middleware that's like the default `ErrorHandlerMiddleware` by modifying these lines: https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/6dbbe831c493e6e7259de81f83a04d1654170137/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.cs#L48-L51 With that approach we could control the redirect path based on the status code.

> In MVC 5 we have had to use the system.web customerrors section for ASP.NET and the system.webServer httpErrors section in the web.config file but it was difficult to work with an unwieldy, with lots of very strange behaviour. Does MVC 6 make this a lot simpler?

**Answer:** It sure does :). Just like the above answer the fix lies in adding middleware. There's a shortcut to adding simple middleware via the `IApplicationBuilder` in your `Startup.cs`; at the end of your `Configure` method you can add the following:

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Could not handle the request.");

    // Nothing else will run after this middleware.
});
```

This will work because it means that you reached the end of your http pipeline without the request being handled (since it's at the end of your `Configure` method in `Startup.cs`). If you want to add this middleware (in the quick fashion) with the option to execute middleware after you, here's how:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Could not handle the request.");

    // This ensures that any other middelware added after you runs.
    await next();
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Presumably this is a replacement for the customErrors section of web.config only and would not work for 404 not found errors. For that we would still need to use httpErrors?

Comment: This would also work for 404 not found errors. A 404 occurs when nothing can handle the request.